# Apache .htaccess doesn't allow website to access assets in restricted folder

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have an issue where in my web directory the assets folder (which is restricted to normal http requests) is inaccessible through the actual web server. For example, the assets stored there are purely images these images cannot be loaded onto the web page as the web page is denied access.

Here is my current .htaccess file setup in my assets folder:

```
order deny,allow

deny from all

allow from 127.0.0.1
```

Maybe I'm really missing something here, but any help is appreciated.

Comment: You're blocking everyone from accessing the files. 127.0.0.1 is your local address, so if you're not accessing this locally, nobody will be able to access them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the issue immediately as I posted this. I had a mega brain fart but all I needed to do was to disable directory index listing, simply alter this in your /etc/apache2/apache2.conf:

```
<Directory /www/...some directory...>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks #Change this line here
    AllowOverride None
</Directory>


<Directory /www/...some directory...>
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
    </Directory>
```

Answer (score 0):

use your local IP, not the 127.0.0.1, you may have one IP that you are using to access your network, add that IP, it might be something like 192.168.1.10

so use:

```
order deny,allow

deny from all

allow from 192.168.1.10
```